# Java: Interface reference?

Tags: java, interface

We all know that you can't instantiate an interface in Java (directly at least).

But with something like this:

```
public class Test{
    public interface Link {
      void mySamplemethod();
      String myString ="HELLO!";
     }

     public static void main(String []args){

        Link b;

     }
}
```

What exactly **is** b... and how could it ever have a practical purpose?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)

Comment: `b` is a reference to an object which must be an instance of class which implements `Link`

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I... don't think so. The other seems to be on the general OOP point of having interfaces...

Comment: It could have a purpose when later on you do: `b = new SubclassOfLink()`. If you have no subclasses of `Link` then you probably had no need to declare the variable.

Comment: @Duncan: no, that question is exactly what you're asking: *what is the purpose of defining a variable as an implemented interface rather than the actual class*. That's your practical purpose right there.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel ... so half my answer then

Comment: Just to add, it is not good practice to initialize variables inside Interfaces, such as `String myString ="HELLO!";`, because it is considered as implementation, which should be left outside and interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`b` is a variable of type `Link` that has no value, not even `null`. In order to have a practical purpose you must initialize it with an object reference whose class implements `Link` interface.

If you want to initialize `Link` with a non-`null` value, you should create a class that implements this interface. That's mandatory in Java. If you don't want to create a new class outside this class, you can create a new class inside the class or inside the method (which would be an [anonymous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)). Here's a sample:

```
public static void main(String []args){
    Link b = new Link() {
        @Override
        public void mySampleMethod() {
            System.out.println("hello");
        }
    };
    b.mySampleMethod();
}
```

The purposes of using interfaces for programming instead of direct classes is already explained very well here: [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/1065197) (no need to reinvent the wheel).

Comment: @Duncan every local variable lives in the stack. And it can be initialized using an anonymous class. Check my answer edit.

Comment: Local variables may live in registers, too. Unless you're talking about the bytecode, where *everything* lives on the stack.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a reference to an interface - you just cannot instantiate it. Let's say for example you have a interface A

```
public interface A {
    public void someMethod();
}
```

Now you have another class that implements this interface

```
public class B implements A {
    public void someMethod() { // do something }
    public void someOtherMethod() { // do something else }
}
```

Now you can have something like

```
A a = new B();
```

While a reference type A it actually implements the method as defined in B. The object type is B. The reference type A indicates that it has only access to those methods in B that are specified by A and nothing else (in this case, it has access to someMethod() and not someOtherMethod()).

Answer (score 1):

> What exactly *is* b...

`b` contains a reference to an instance of a class that implements `Link`. The reference can, of course, be `null`.

> and how could it ever have a practical purpose?

Its practical purpose is pretty much the same as any other Java reference.

Of course, the code as it is does not really put `b` to any use. However, it's not hard to imagine similar code that would (you'd need to have a class that implements `Link`, and create an instance of that class).

Answer (score 1):

For instance interfaces are widely used in polymorphism. So if you have multiple classes implementing interface, you could keep them in the same way:

```
class One implements Link {..}
class Two implements Link {..}

public static void main(String[] arg) {

  Vector<Link> links;
  Link link1 = new One();
  Link link2 = new Two();

  links.add(link1);
  links.add(link2);

  for (Link l : links) {
    l.mySampleMethod();
  }
}
```